# display pandas dataframe on flask html with embeds inside?

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I'm trying to render a pandas DF using flask html. I have two columns, one that is just a string and the other contains a url. I am trying to combine the two into a third column that displays the string but also links the url.

heres my python code:

```
def make_clickable(url, name):
    return '<a href="{}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">{}</a>'.format(url,name)
df['link'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_clickable(x['url'], x['name']), axis=1)
return render_template('home.html', tables=[df1[0:20].to_html(header="true", index= False, justify="center")])
```

and below is my html for the table, for which I'm using Jinja

```
{% for table in tables %}

{{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

The result I'm getting is that the html code is simply being rendered as text rather than red as html. I was wondering if there were alternative html code that could allow me to customize the table in a way that the html code is properly run?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def make_clickable(url, name):
return '<a href="{}" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">{ </a>'.format(url, name)

df['link'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_clickable(x['url'], x['name']), axis=1)
df_html = df[0:20].to_html(header="true", index=False, justify="center")
return render_template('home.html', table_html=df_html)
```

The result html should be something like:

```
{% autoescape true %}
<table>
  {{ table_html|safe }}
</table>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Tried this but it seems to have the same result as before unfortunately

Comment: managed to fix it using html.unescape and then doing |safe